# Links between service Rancher Server 1.0.0

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, rancher

I'm porting my docker environment to rancher server 1.0.0.

I have a wordpress container which is linked to a mysql container.
Each one are in separate stack: One stack for the wordpress container and one for the mysql container.

Previously, linking between those two container was achieve using a ***docker-compose.yml*** for my wordpress container containing:

```
wordpress:  
    external_links:
        - mysql:mysql
```

This was working perfectly before, but not anymore when those containers are within a rancher server.

The documentation about DNS service is not clear for me:
http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/rancher-services/internal-dns-service/

In rancher, my stack is named ***mysql*** and my service ***mysql***.

I have tried to link using what

```
wordpress:
    external_links:
        - mysql.mysql:mysql
```

But this does not works too.

Those two containers are in a custom catalog, the only way right now to make this work is to create and start the two services and then change linking by upgrading the wordpress service afterward.

Any idea ?
I'm i missing something ?

Thanks a lots !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

Instead of:

```
    external_links:
        - mysql.mysql:mysql
```

Use the following syntax for linking service within a stack:

```
    external_links:
        - mysql/mysql:mysql
```

Or more generically:

```
    external_links:
        - stack_name/service_name:alias_name
```

Hope this help !